# How to animate a custom UIButton?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uibutton, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to animate a custom UIButton but my code doesn't seems to work. I'm using this in ViewDidLoad:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:40.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
        duckButton.frame = CGRectMake(120, 80, 120, 180);
        duckButton.frame = CGRectMake(200, 90, 120, 180);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
```

What should I do?

> [Edit: The answer is on the comments]

Comment: It tried it and it works fine

Comment: i'm missing something here. :/

Comment: Exaclty the same, are you sure this code is called ?

Comment: pretty sure, idk why isn't working.. :'(

Comment: I've tried with a backgroundView and works just fine... But the button still don't work... how can this be happening?! it doesn't make any sense,,,

Comment: A couple things that I would check for first:
1) Is viewDidLoad being called?
2) Is duckButton valid at the time viewDidLoad is being called?

Comment: Also, you are telling your duck button to relocate to 2 different positions in the same amount of time. It can't go to 2 places at once.

Comment: Yeah... vDL is being called and the dB is valid.

Comment: Wow, checking the second comment.

Comment: I leave one frame and still not working.

Comment: If you set the duckButton's frame without the animation block, does it move to a different location instantaneously?

Comment: No, it doesn't move at all. Stays in the mid of the View

Comment: Then I go back to something I pointed to earlier. duckButton is almost certainly nil at the point where you are trying to change the frame. If you do a NSLog(@"%@", duckButton) in viewDidLoad, then you will see this.

Comment: The NSLog works... It gives me null 
2012-05-10 16:52:41.738 duckPingv2[1612:10703] (null)

Comment: Right, which means that your duckButton is nil. Since it is nil, it has no frame. Your duckButton needs to be created either in the init method or in the viewDidLoad method prior to trying to animate it. Otherwise it will not work.

Comment: FINALLY! IT WORKS!!! Thanks for helping! I really appreciate it :)

((Can't accept a comment like an answer, if u like, make the answer so I can give you the reputation. ))

Comment: I'm not too worried about getting reputation. I'm glad that I could help!

Comment: @iJordan: It's not as much a matter of reputation as it is about actually getting the question answered. If you *don't want* the rep you can always wiki the answer, but I see no reason to do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm bringing out what I said in the comments to make it as an actual answer as suggested by BoltClock.

I want to point out that there really is no issue with the code (except that the frame is set for two different final locations). The issue is that the button was not properly initialized prior to execution of the animation block, and since a nil object can not have a frame it essentially did nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Set the initial frame position before beginning your animation block and then have only your end position in the animation block.

Comment: Also, I think you've forgotten to include the return type of your animation block?